# Хранение иерархической структуры со стандартными(повторяющимися) элементами в реляционной БД

Tags: база-данных

Вся найденная мной информация о методах хранения иерархических структур описывает ситуации, где каждый элемент в иерархии уникален.

Но как быть если элемент списка входит в несколько  ветвей сразу?
Например как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь деталь 2 - это та же самая деталь, с теми же значениями полей - той же массой, тем же цветом, из того же материала и т.д.

Я понимаю, что если моделировать реальный физический объект, то это будет уже другая деталь и ей можно присвоить другой ID. Но тогда их надо рассматривать как экземпляры и надо делать отдельные таблицы где маппить каждый тип детали (класс) к экземплярам, чтоб если я решу изменить цвет, он изменился на всех таких деталях.

То есть получится одна таблица - хранящая все классы (типы деталей) и их поля  и вторая таблица, хранящая все экземпляры, иерархию экземпляров и ссылку на базовый класс для каждого экземпляра. Примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос заключается в том, насколько применим такой подход и существуют ли иные методы хранения иерархической структуры в данном случае?

Спасибо!

UPD:
Появилась альтернативная мысль - замапить таблицу саму на себя через соотношение множество к множеству:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой из этих способов предпочтительнее?